# How I can format date in report to appear exactly as I want - RDLC

Tags: visual-studio-2010, reporting-services, rdlc, report

I have a report in my application and this report will show a long date from db and I used this expression to make it shorter:

```
=FormatDateTime(Fields!StatementDate.Value,DateFormat.ShortDate)
```

and the date will show like this : `1/1/2010`

I need to make it like this : 2010/1/1

How I can do it?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

That expression do the trick

```
=CDate(Fields!Fecha.Value).ToString("yyyy/M/d")
```

Answer (score 9):

I think that it is a lot cleaner to use the `Format` property rather than format it in your expressions:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252080%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

You can use the standard .NET formatting strings.

```
Value=Fields!StatementDate.Value
Format=yyyy/M/d
```

Fields!StatementDate.Value will need to be a DateTime, if not you can try convert it:

```
Value=CDate(Fields!StatementDate.Value)
```

Comment: thank you it's better approach because one can handle null value with it

Comment: Agreed, however in my report, I have a "Payroll Period" that I need to format `FromDate - ToDate`. So for the purposes of the search that brought me to this question, @pcofre's answer did the trick. Normally, when I want to apply a custom format to a single date column, I would definitely use your approach.

Answer (score 1):

```
=CDate(Fields!StatementDate.Value).ToShortDateString()
```